# Why does TypeError appear occasionally?

Tags: python

My python scrapping program is running into TypeError.

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, feedparser

cqrss = feedparser.parse('https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/new.rss')

for submission in cqrss.entries:
    folder_name = submission.title #use for create folder
    reddit_url = submission.link
    source = requests.get(reddit_url)
    plain_text = source.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')
    title = soup.find('a', 'title may-blank outbound', href=True)
    if 'imgur.com' in title['href']:
        imgur_link = title['href']
    print(imgur_link)
```

Error:

```
if 'imgur.com' in title['href']:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It means that the 'href' key in title is None (null). So check if it is null first, then get the link if it's not null.

Comment: @Steampunkery I think that complaint about `title` being not subscriptable, means there is no `href` key in the 1st place, not even missing, it can't be there. If the value under `href` was `None` I think it would say that the value is *non-iterable*.

Comment: @luk32 wouldn’t it throw a keyerror if the key didn’t exist?

Comment: @Steampunkery Yes, if they key didn't exist in `title`, but for even being possible to check it, `title` should be subscriptable. It is not. You can't even probe for the key. Executing `title['href']` is already wrong.

Comment: @luk32 how should I properly extract the title link?

Answer (score 2):

`find` "fails" (i.e. does not find anything) for some data and returns `None`.

```
if title and 'imgur.com' in title['href']:
    imgur_link = title['href']
    print(imgur_link)
```

should work.

Note that `print` was moved under the `if` clause, as it obviously does not make sense to call it, if data isn't there.